# Entity Framework many to one when one entity is not on the database

Tags: entity-framework

I have this two related classes on my model.

```
public class Project 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set;}
  public virtual AdUser Creator { get; set; }
}

public class AdUser 
{
  public virtual string Id { get; set; }
  public List<string> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The table for the model is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatorId] VARCHAR(100)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Projects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The data source of the `AdUser` class is not the database as it represents an Active Directory user. So I want to be able to store only the Creator.Id property on `CreatorId` column once I call `SaveChanges()` on the context.

On the other hand if I get a Project from the database I just want an empty `Creator` with the `Id` set.

The main idea is to have access to `AdUser` data handled by an independent repository.

I'm targeting Entity Framework 6.0

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the [NotMapped] attribute

```
public class Project 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set;}
  public virtual string CreatorId { get; set; }
  [NotMapped]
  public virtual AdUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```

This will tell EF to ignore the Creator property on your model.

In my opinion you should instead be using a different model for your datatier and application logic here, for example if you want to have a Creator populated by a different piece of business logic, make it return a new object which has that and dont put it in the datatier model. This IMO follows SRP better, ie the model is either for storage or application not both.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an AdUserId mapped on CreatorId private (for the class consumers is a nice approach) and map project explicitly.

```
public class Project 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set;}

  private string AdUserId {
    get { // Read from AdUser 
        } 
    set { // set a backing field for 
          // AdUser lazy load or just set AdUser in an 
          // eagerly load approach 
        }

  // virtual is not required any more
  // If you need insert backing field for lazy load
  public AdUser Creator { get ; set; }

  public  ProjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
  {
    public  ProjectMap()
    {
        Ignore(t => t.AdUser);
        Property(t => t.AdUserId).HasColumnName("CreatorId");
    }

  }

}

public class AdUser 
{
  public virtual string Id { get; set; }
  public List<string> { get; set; }
}
```

In context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Project.ProjectMap());
}
```

Comment: thanks bubi, you almost got something I like. The problem is that I cant access `AdUserId` from `ProjectMap` if it's private and I don't want to make that public and mess up the model with those properties.

Comment: ProjectMap it's an **inner class** of Project. You can access to AdUserId from it...